# Cannot add object of type T to List<T> in java

Tags: java, generics

I have been learning generics in Java. Although I understand the concepts regarding type inference, parameterized classes and methods, I came across a strange scenario while experimenting.

I have implemented a Box class which can be used to hold items of type T. I am using List as an internal data structure for this abstraction. Following is my code:

```
public class Box<T> {

    private List<T> items;

    public Box(){
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public <T> void addItemToBox(T t){
        items.add(t);
    }
}
```

I am getting a compile time error at items.add(t) saying add(T) in List cannot be applied to (T). I am unable to figure out the cause of this error. Also, I don't understand why I can't add an item of type T to a list which is parameterized by T.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've made a local redeclaration of generic type variable `<T>` on your method `addItemToBox` that shadows the one on class `Box<T>`.

The `<T>` on your method is not the same  on `List<T> items;`

Your current code is 100% equivalent to:

```
public class Box<T> {

    private List<T> items;

    public Box(){
        items = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public <T2> void addItemToBox(T2 t){
        items.add(t);
    }
}
```

If you see it that way, it should be clear why your code fails to compile.

**Solution: remove the `<T>` in front of the method declaration**

```
public void addItemToBox(T t)
```

Comment: Thanks Erwin! That made things very clear to me. I was confusing two concepts.